# Docker lamp container connection to DB

Tags: docker, containers, lamp

I pulled this image on docker:

https://hub.docker.com/r/fauria/lamp/

After I launched a container mapping my path to /var/www/html and I've downloaded WordPress file to try the container.

The problem is that I always get this: "Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531"

how can I let WP access to mariaDB?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your dockerfile.

Comment: I didn't use a docker file, anyway it was a WordPress container problem...